# How to work around the first-order constraint on arrows?

Tags: haskell, arrows, yampa

**What I mean by first-order constraint**

First, I'll explain what I mean by first-order constraint on arrows:
Due to the way arrows desugar, you cannot use a locally bound name where an arrow command  is expected in the arrow do-notation.

Here is an example to illustrate:

`proc x -> f -< x + 1` desugars to `arr (\x -> x + 1) >>> f` and similarly `proc x -> g x -< ()` would desugar to `arr (\x -> ()) >>> g x`, where the second `x` is a free variable. The [GHC user guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/arrow-notation.html) explains this and says that when your arrow is also a monad you may make an instance of `ArrowApply` and use `app` to get around this. Something like, `proc x -> g x -<< ()` becomes `arr (\x -> (g x, ())) >>> app`.

**My Question**

Yampa defines the [`accumHold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Yampa/0.9.3/doc/html/FRP-Yampa.html#v%3aaccumHold) function with this type: `a -> SF (Event (a -> a)) a`.
Due to this first-order limitation of arrows, I'm struggling to write the following function:

```
accumHoldNoiseR :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => (a,a) -> g -> SF (Event (a -> a)) a
accumHoldNoiseR r g = proc f -> do
  n <- noiseR r g -< ()
  accumHold n -< f
```

The definition above doesn't work because `n` is not in scope after desugaring.

Or, similarly this function, where the first part of the pair to `SF` is meant to be the initial value passed to `accumHold`

```
accumHold' :: SF (a,Event (a -> a)) -> a
accumHold' = ...
```

Is there some combinator or trick that I'm missing? Or is it not possible to write these definitions without an `ArrowApply` instance?

**tl;dr:** Is it possible to define `accumHoldNoiseR :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => (a,a) -> g -> SF (Event (a -> a)) a` or `accumHold' :: SF (a,Event (a -> a)) -> a` in yampa?

**Note:** There is no instance of `ArrowApply` for `SF`. My understanding is that it doesn't make sense to define one either. See ["Programming with Arrows"](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/afp-arrows.pdf) for details.

Comment: I'm not an arrow expert, so I don't know if you need `ArrowApply` or not, but one way to approach the problem is to ask yourself what you think your code without the first-order limitation should desugar to.

Comment: The use of 'n' in 'accumHold n -< f' is out of scope, but I suspect that '-<<' can replace '-<' here and make 'n' to be in scope.

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz `-<<` requires an `ArrowApply` instance so it doesn't make sense here (ie., you can't make `SF` into a monad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a theoretical answer. Look to [Roman Cheplyaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17389192/1598537) to this question, which deals more with the practical details of what you're trying to achieve.

---

The reason `n` is out of scope is that for it to be in scope to use there, you would have the equivalent of `bind` or `>>=` from monads. It's the use of the results of a previous computation as a functional input to the next which makes something as powerful as a monad.

Hence you can supply `n` as a function argument to a subsequent arrow exactly when you can make an ArrowApply instance.

Chris Kuklewicz correctly points out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385635/how-to-work-around-the-first-order-constraint-on-arrows/17391792#comment25244457_17385635) that `-<<` would bring `n` into scope - it also uses `app`, so you need an ArrowApply instance.

### Summary

Not unless you use ArrowApply. This is what ArrowApply is for.

Answer (score 2):

`noiseR` is a signal function; it produces a *stream* of random numbers, not just one random number (for that, you'd just use `randomR` from `System.Random`).

On the other hand, the first argument of `accumHold` is just one, initial, value.

So this is not just some limitation — it actually prevents you from committing a type error.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, then simply using `randomR` should do the trick. Otherwise, please clarify why you need `noiseR`.

Comment: I used `randomR` (instead of `noiseR`) inside `accumHoldNoiseR`, it would give me a local binding and so I wouldn't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To help others understand how I worked around this I'll answer my own question.

I was trying to implement the game pong. I wanted the ball to start with a random velocity each round. I wanted to use `accumHold` to define the ball's velocity. I had some code like this:

```
ballPos = proc e -> mdo -- note the recursive do
  {- some clipping calculations using (x,y) -}
  ...
  vx <- accumHold 100 -< e `tag` collisionResponse paddleCollision
  vy <- accumHold 100 -< e `tag` collisionResponse ceilingFloorCollision
  (x,y) <- integral -< (vx,vy)
  returnA -< (x,y)
```

I wanted to replace the 100s with random values (presumably from `noiseR`).

How I solved this instead is to accumulate over the direction, where `collisionResponse` just flips the sign (eventually I'll want to use the angle of the velocity relative to wall/paddle):

```
ballPos = proc (initV, e) -> mdo
  {- some clipping calculations using (x,y) -}
  ...
  (iVx,iVy) <- hold (0,0) -< initV
  vx <- accumHold 1 -< e `tag` collisionResponse paddleCollision
  vy <- accumHold 1 -< e `tag` collisionResponse ceilingFloorCollision
  (x,y) <- integral -< (iVx*vx,iVy*vy)
  returnA -< (x,y)
```

**Lesson Learned:**

You can often separate the value/state you want to accumulate into a behavior describing how it changes and a "magnitude" that describes its current value taking the behavior as input. In my case, I separate out the magnitude of the initial velocity, pass that as input to the signal function, and use `accumHold` to compute the affect on the ball (the behavior) of having collisions. So regardless of what the initial velocity was, hitting the walls "reflects" the ball. And that's exactly what the `accumHold` is accumulating.